# Problems deleting and creating file on SD card

Tags: android, sd-card, createfile, delete-file

Theres a problem I can't seem to fix:
In my `OnCreate` in the `CameraActivity`, I delete the picture first if it's there. If there is a situation where this is done, the picture file is created but the picture is blank. (so only creates the picture successfully if the file isn't there in the first place). How do I delete the file and create it successfully?

My `CameraActivity` is defined as follows:

```
    public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{   
    final int PICTURE_ACTIVITY = 1; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {  


        Intent h = getIntent();
        String filename = h.getStringExtra("string") + ".jpg";

        String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/" + getString(R.string.app_name)+ "/"; 
        File newdir = new File(dir); 
        try{
            newdir.mkdirs();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        String file = dir + filename;
        File newfile = new File(file);
        boolean deleted = newfile.delete();

        try {
            System.out.println("creating:");
            newfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {} 

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PICTURE_ACTIVITY);
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your createAlertDialog is in the onActivityResult() right?

Comment: Put it outside of onActivityResult as a method of your activity class.

Comment: @user370305 You mean call another method in onActivityResult which displays the alert dialog?

Comment: Yes, and remove it from onActivityResult..

Comment: @user370305 I did what you said, and it didn't make a difference. I have updated my first post with my edited code.

Comment: I was able to fix problem 1) and 3) by putting dialog.cancel() as the first statement in my OnClick() for the Alertdialog

Comment: I realised the reason it wasn't saving sometimes was because I was taking the SD card out of the phone before it had the chance to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the reason it wasn't saving sometimes was because I was taking the SD card out of the phone before it had the chance to save.